# OrientDB - compare 2 vertex, with edge property

Tags: sql, graph-databases, orientdb

I have two types of vertices (**Car** and **Attribute**), and one type of edges (**Property**):

```
CREATE CLASS Car extends V
CREATE CLASS Attribute extends V
CREATE CLASS Property extends E
```

The **Attribute** holds the available properties, let's say **engine**, **color**, **year** and **model**.

And the **Car** should hold the link to those attributes:

```
CREATE VERTEX Attribute SET attributeName = "engine"
CREATE VERTEX Attribute SET attributeName = "color"
CREATE VERTEX Attribute SET attributeName = "year"
CREATE VERTEX Attribute SET attributeName = "model"
```

(Is there a faster way to create these without 4 queries?)

```
CREATE VERTEX Car SET name = "Suzuki"
CREATE VERTEX Car SET name = "Honda"

CREATE EDGE Property from (SELECT FROM Car WHERE name = "Suzuki") to (SELECT FROM Attribute WHERE attributeName = "color") SET value = "pink"

CREATE EDGE Property from (SELECT FROM Car WHERE name = "Suzuki") to (SELECT FROM Attribute WHERE attributeName = "model") SET value = "Alto"

CREATE EDGE Property from (SELECT FROM Car WHERE name = "Suzuki") to (SELECT FROM Attribute WHERE attributeName = "year") SET value = 2005


CREATE EDGE Property from (SELECT FROM Car WHERE name = "Honda") to (SELECT FROM Attribute WHERE attributeName = "color") SET value = "black"

CREATE EDGE Property from (SELECT FROM Car WHERE name = "Honda") to (SELECT FROM Attribute WHERE attributeName = "engine") SET value = 2500

CREATE EDGE Property from (SELECT FROM Car WHERE name = "Honda") to (SELECT FROM Attribute WHERE attributeName = "model") SET value = "Civic"

CREATE EDGE Property from (SELECT FROM Car WHERE name = "Honda") to (SELECT FROM Attribute WHERE attributeName = "year") SET value = 2005
```

(Again, any faster way?)

Now I would like to make a search for any Car with color black (**Honda** should be returned).

But when I search for any car from year 2005 and engine of 2500, although **Suzuki** doesn't have **engine** attribute, it should be returned too (so **Honda** and **Suzuki**).

I tried the following query:

```
select distinct(out.Car) as car from Property WHERE 
                    (in.attributeName="engine" AND value=2500) OR 
                    (in.attributeName="year" AND value=2005)
```

And of course, **Suzuki** was returned too.. any help?

Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Hi @Itay Elkouby. You want cars from year 2005 __and__ engine of 2500? Or you want cars from year 2005 __or__ engine of 2500? I'm having trouble understanding what's your problem.

Comment: I want  engine and year.. but suzuki should return too as he doesnt have the attribute "engine",

Comment: You're iterating through all your edges and if they respect some conditions, then return some value. Now, if the edge does not exist, I can't see how you're gonna return what you want. Regarding your first question, you can: `INSERT INTO Attribute (attributeName) VALUES ("engine"),("color"),("year"),("model")`

Comment: I see.. well thank you! by this i decided to not use the "graph" mode, but use a more simple document mode, please can you try and answer my next question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29914549/orientdb-cant-delete-value-from-map