# orientDB cant delete value from map

Tags: sql, orientdb

I been trying the following query:

```
UPDATE #15:1 REMOVE jsonData.contactName
```

And receive the following

```
{
"result": [
    {
        "@type": "d",
        "@version": 0,
        "value": 1
    }
],
"notification": "Query executed in 0.027 sec. Returned 1 record(s)"
}
```

Which mean been succedd,

Now when i query to check the value i get:

```
select * from #15:1

{
"result": [
    {
        "@type": "d",
        "@rid": "#15:1",
        "@version": 6,
        "@class": "TestClass",
        "postUrl": "ABC",
        "postCategory": "#11:497",
        "jsonData": {
            "contactName": "JHON"
        },
        "@fieldTypes": "postCategory=x"
    }
],
"notification": "Query executed in 0.023 sec. Returned 1 record(s)"
```

}

Also it seem that when i save boolean variable into the map, the boolean is casting to string (false => "false").. is there a way to save integers, boolean and string in the same map?

Answer (score 0):

See [here](http://orientdb.com/docs/last/SQL-Update.html) (example 6).

```
UPDATE #15:1 REMOVE jsonData = 'contactName'
```

Comment: Getting "success" but the value contactName keeps and not delete

Comment: Which OrientDB version?

Comment: BTW, do you know how to case datetime to date? 
SELECT DATE(dateTimeVariable) FROM testClass
Doesnt seem to work

Comment: Don't know, never done it. Mine is __2.0.7__ too, weird.

Comment: Should consider it as a bug? what is the prosedure to open a new bug?

Comment: It's not a bug probably. Since we have the same version and I managed to get it working. About bugs, take a look to OrientDB Github.

Comment: See if [this](https://gist.github.com/vitorenesduarte/f5742ff2c7e7b0f1d19d) works for you.